# How to format MySQL timestamp using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, date

I read timestamp from `MySQL` db (is type `timestamp`).

Like this: `2017-04-01 15:34:31`

I want to format this date using `jquery` and set up to some `span` element.

I am new in `jquery` and I don't know how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: It's a good thing to add a comment on the answers received as to whether they helped and in what way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)` function in `MySQL`. Something like:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
```

would give you 04-01-2017. Then wrap that in a `<span>`.

If you are using PHP then

```
strftime('%m-%d-%Y',$timestamp);
```

is an alternative. there are plenty of examples in Stack Overflow; Google will get you there.

Comment: Downvoted for not answering the question. He asked how to format it with jQuery, not PHP, and not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you would are receving the `timestamp` on the client side you can [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

```js
// Create a new JavaScript Date object based on the timestamp
// multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds.
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);

// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();

// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();

// Seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

// Will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
```

To add the formatted text to a `span` you could use javascript or jQuery

```js
// Javascript
document.querySelector("span").text(formattedTime);

// jQuery
$("span").text(formattedTime);
```

For more information regarding the `Date` object, please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or the [ECMAScript 5 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9).

Additionally:

- If you must use jQuery instead of Javascript, consider a plugin
  https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat
- There is Javascript library https://momentjs.com/ for time
- There is a great JS talk about time https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BdFg5JT9lg

Answer (score 0):

```
Date(Date.parse(data.timestamp[i]))
```

This works assuming you are iterating through timestamps sent to the frontend from a Mysql query, which returns arrays. You could also write it like:

```
Date(Date.parse("2020-01-08 06:36:59"))
```